# Error creating DB entry in model with nested has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1

Setup:

Reservations can be assigned multiple Resources. A reservation-resource combo can have multiple SetUps.

I tried to set up the model like this:

```
class SetUp < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
  has_many :resources, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
end

class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_resources, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_resources
  has_many :set_ups, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_resources, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :resources, through: :reservation_resources
  has_many :set_ups, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
end

class ReservationResource < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reservation
  belongs_to :resource
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups
  has_many :set_ups, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
end

class ReservationResourceSetUp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reservation
  belongs_to :resource
  belongs_to :set_up
end
```

Steps:

1. Create a reservation, assigning a resource, works:

   ```
   res1 = Reservation.create(name:"res name")
   res1.resources << Resource.find(1)  # resource with id = 1 exists
   ```

   The reservations and reservation_resources tables are updated correctly.
2. Assign a setup to the reservation_resource, fails:

   ```
   res1.resources.first.set_ups << SetUp.find(1) # set_ups with id = 1 exists
   ```

   This fails with error `ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid (Validation failed: Reservation must exist)`

Can you help point me in the right direction?  Thanks!

(Here's the schema, if helpful...)

```
create_table "reservation_resource_set_ups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "reservation_id"
  t.integer "resource_id"
  t.integer "set_up_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["reservation_id"], name: "index_reservation_resource_set_ups_on_reservation_id"
  t.index ["resource_id"], name: "index_reservation_resource_set_ups_on_resource_id"
  t.index ["set_up_id"], name: "index_reservation_resource_set_ups_on_set_up_id"
end

create_table "reservation_resources", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "reservation_id"
  t.integer "resource_id"
  t.text "comments"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["reservation_id"], name: "index_reservation_resources_on_reservation_id"
  t.index ["resource_id"], name: "index_reservation_resources_on_resource_id"
end

create_table "reservations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"

  ...

  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["end_date"], name: "index_reservations_on_end_date"
  t.index ["repeat_end_date"], name: "index_reservations_on_repeat_end_date"
  t.index ["start_date"], name: "index_reservations_on_start_date"
end

create_table "resources", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.text "description"
  t.string "resource_type"
  t.text "location"
  t.integer "quantity", default: 1
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "set_ups", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.text "instructions"
  t.string "image"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

Answer (score 1):

<< method useless when you need to setup more than one foreign key.

The collection<< method adds one or more objects to the collection by setting their foreign keys to the primary key of the calling model.

So you cat treat the code

```
res1.resources.first.set_ups << SetUp.find(1) # set_ups with id = 1 exists
```

as

```
ReservationResourceSetUp.create(
  set_up: SetUp.find(1), # from << SetUp.find(1)
  resource: res1.resources.first, # from left side
  reservation: nil # raises the error
)
```

To create the entry, just specify all the keys:

```
ReservationResourceSetUp.create(
  set_up: SetUp.find(1),
  resource: res1.resources.first,
  reservation: res1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some problems with your models. For example:

- ReservationResource `has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups`. ActiveRecord assumes a reservation_resource_id in ReservationResourceSetUp

but

- ReservationResourceSetUp does not `belongs_to :reservation_resource`

I suggest some changes in your models:

```
class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_resources, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_resources
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups, through: :reservation_resources
  has_many :set_ups, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_resources, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :resources, through: :reservation_resources
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups, through: :reservation_resources
  has_many :set_ups, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
end

class ReservationResource < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reservation
  belongs_to :resource
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups
  has_many :set_ups, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
end

class SetUp < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reservation_resource_set_ups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :reservations_resources, through: :reservation_resource_set_ups
  has_many :resources, through: :reservation_resources
  has_many :reservations, through: :reservation_resources
end

class ReservationResourceSetUp < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reservation_resource
  belongs_to :set_up
end
```

The main change is that ReservationResourceSetUp now belongs to ReservationResource and SetUp (instead of Reservation, Resource and SetUp). In practice it's the same, but I think it handles your situation in a better way. You first create a Reservation for a Resource. This ReservationResource is then assigned one or more SetUps. I think your code would work if you make these changes. You must of course change your migrations. Now your ReservationResourceSetUp will have a reservation_resource_id and a set_up_id.